# How to save objects (in this case, players) in a list in C++?

Tags: c++, list, object, save

I have a class player with the following: int posx, int posy, and int color.

```
void jugador::dibujar_jugador() // void draw player
{
    gotoxy(x,y);
    color(col);
    cout << "   O";
    gotoxy(x, y+1);
    cout << "  <|> ";
    gotoxy(x, y+2);
    cout << "  / \\";
}
```

I then created a team to store the players, with the following: jugador vec[6] and int ultimo. Int ultimo is for the last position of the list.

```
equipo::equipo() //Team
{
    ultimo=-1; //Last position starts at -1
}

void equipo:: insertar_jugador(jugador J1) //Insert player
{
    ultimo++; //vec increases size by 1
    vec[ultimo] = J1;
}

void equipo:: mostrar_equipo(jugador boy) //Show team
{
    int cont;
    for (cont=0; cont<6; cont++) // When I change "<6" to "<=ultimo", the players don't show.
    {
        insertar_jugador(boy); // Insert player
        vec[cont].dibujar_jugador(); //Draw player from vec
        if (boy.Getcol() == 11)
        {
            boy.Setx(rand()%20);
            boy.Sety(rand()%27);
        }
        else if (boy.Getcol() == 12)
        {
            boy.Setx(rand()%56);
            boy.Sety(rand()%27);
        }
    }
}
```

The procedure to show a team only works when I enter 6 (any value other than "ultimo"), and I know it's because nothing is being saved. However, why isn't anything saving in the list of players?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `boy` by value.

```
void equipo:: mostrar_equipo(jugador boy)//show team
```

Inside the function, `boy` is a temporary.  As soon as that function exits, `boy` no longer exists.  You need to pass `boy` by reference:

```
void equipo:: mostrar_equipo(jugador& boy)//show team
```

Also, when you call `insertar_jugador`, that parameter is also passed by value, making `insertar_jugador` insert a copy of `boy` in vec.  But your changes later on (you calling `boy.Setx` and `boy.Sety`) has no effect on the `boy` you placed in the vec array.

Why not just have a `std::vector<jugador>`?  When you want to change one of the players, just get it from the `vector` by using `vector::operator []` or `vector::at()`, since both these functions return references to the `boy` you placed in the vector.

Comment: I don't know how to use std::vector<jugador>, but I'll google it right now! Thanks for the idea!